# How can I use slug candidates with frienldy_id and simple_i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, translate, friendly-id

In a Rails4 app, I use `friendly_id` 5.0.1 with the plugin `simple_i18n` with two locales `en` and `de`.

In my model, I have `name_de`, `name_en` and `title_de`, `title_en` (and of cause `slug_de`, `slug_en`).
When saving the model, I used to set both slugs in a `before_save` hook:

```
def set_slug
  set_friendly_id name_de, :de
  set_frinedly_id name_en, :en
end
```

Now I'd like to use the new `slug_candidates` functionality.

How can I do that?

```
def set_slug
  set_friendly_id [:name_de,:title_de], :de
  set_frinedly_id [:name_en,:title_en], :en
end
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

FriendlyId author here. Sorry, at the moment that is not implemented, which really is an oversight on my part. I will try to add that functionality soon.